# Make one column with named same columns after UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Table1
id | col1 | col2 | other_id
---------------------------
1  | val1 | val2 | 2
2  | val3 | val4 | 3

Table2
id | col3 | other_id
--------------------
1  | val5 | 4
```

And I want to join this two tables in this way:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | other_id
-----------------------------------
1  | val1 | val2 | NULL | 2
2  | val3 | val4 | NULL | 3
1  | NULL | NULL | val5 | 4
```

I create this SQL query:

```
(
SELECT * FROM table1 AS M LEFT JOIN table2 AS D ON M.other_id = D.other_id
)
UNION
(
SELECT * FROM table1 AS M RIGHT JOIN table2 AS D ON M.other_id = D.other_id
)
```

Result:

```
id   | col1 | col2 | other_id | id   | col3 | other_id
------------------------------------------------------
1    | val1 | val2 | 2        | NULL | NULL | NULL
2    | val3 | val4 | 3        | NULL | NULL | NULL
NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL     | 1    | val5 | 4
```

But I get multiple columns with same labels. I don't want to use aliases, just join columns with the same name.

Comment: Please don't put the solution in your question. Instead accept any answer if it solve your problem. If none of the given answers solve your problem and you have the solution then you can add your own answer on your own post. :)

Comment: Ok :) I'm new and I'm still learning rules and manners. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` for this and just put placeholders for the columns that do not exist in both tables:

```
select t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2, null col3, t1.other_id
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.id, null col1, null col2, t2.col3, t2.other_id
from table2 t2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6213d/6)

Result:

```
| ID |   COL1 |   COL2 |   COL3 | OTHER_ID |
--------------------------------------------
|  1 |   val1 |   val2 | (null) |        2 |
|  2 |   val3 |   val4 | (null) |        3 |
|  1 | (null) | (null) |   val5 |        4 |
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve this without using *alias*, you have to use each column manually.

```
(SELECT M.ID,M.Col1,M.Col2,D.Col3,M.Other_ID 
   FROM table1 AS M 
   LEFT JOIN table2 AS D 
   ON M.other_id = D.other_id)
UNION
(SELECT D.ID,M.Col1,M.Col2,D.Col3,D.Other_ID 
   FROM table1 AS M 
   RIGHT JOIN table2 AS D 
   ON M.other_id = D.other_id);
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d566/18)

Result

```
| ID |   COL1 |   COL2 |   COL3 | OTHER_ID |
--------------------------------------------
|  1 |   val1 |   val2 | (null) |        2 |
|  2 |   val3 |   val4 | (null) |        3 |
|  1 | (null) | (null) |   val5 |        4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, ''  col3, other_id
FROM table1 

UNION

SELECT id, '' col1 , '' col2, col3, other_id 
FROM table2
```

Comment: Ok, I solved this in little bit different way. Details in edit :)

Answer (score -1):

Union wants that the tables has the same fields. You can put 'artificial' fields to do that